# Shipping rates not working after installing OneStep CheckOut extension

Tags: shipping, extensions

I have **WebShop Matrix Rates** extension in my store through which I have defined city-to-city and weight wise rates.They work perfectly fine without this new OneStep Checkout extension however when I enable this extension the rates do not get displayed in one step checkout page and the product is billed without shipping rate. Any help?
The one step checkout extension is **Lotus Breath-One Step Checkout**

Comment: Did you ever faced by following issue?  Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps metrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.

Answer (score 2):

I am using version 3.1.2 of **LotusBreath One Step Checkout** and I had the same problem. U only have to uncomment one line of code

On file **/app/code/local/Lotusbreath/OneStepCheckout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php**

Uncomment line 55

```
$this->getAddress()->save()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
```

Refresh cache and you are done ;D

Comment: can you help me regard Matrix rate https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/241323/39050 @Rohit, Carlos

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the code that displays the shipping rates in the One Step Checkout extension, and also take a look at the code in WebShop Matrix Rates to ensure it's correct.

Without looking at the code, I'd assume the WebShop Matrix Rates layout XML file (Probably in `design/frontend/base/default/layout`) references the `<checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>` block which is probably different to that of your One Step Checkout extension.